# Behavior of git and less in iTerm2 and Zsh - do not use separate view/alternate screen

Tags: git, zsh, iterm2, less-unix

Using `less`-like commands in Zsh with iTerm2, e.g. running `git log --graph -n 3`, `git stash list`, or `less README.md`, puts the output in a separate view. I would like the behavior to be more like `cat` where the output stays in the main window. E.g. when I am using `git log`, I want to be able to refer back to the commit hashes I just saw.

Comment: See also http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/how-to-configure-screen-restore-in-a-terminal (though specifically for iTerm2 the setting is easier!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix is an iTerm2 [setting](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html) "Disable save/restore alternate screen" found in iTerm2>Preferences>Terminal. Checking the associated box gives the desired behavior.

Comment: Not sure where this knob was back then when this question was originally answered, but as of today, the new location is this one: Iterm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> (your current profile) -> Terminal -> "Disable save/restore alternate screen".